# Unable to trigger change after changing value in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I'm trying to change a value in a dropdown box and then trigger the event that happens when the value changes. The code is quite simple and looks like this:

```
    zScalerEndPointList.on("change", function(){
        // Change the value
        $("select#phase1_type").val("string:ddns");
        // Trigger the change
        $("select#phase1_type").trigger("change");
    })
```

The value is successfully changed, but the event is not triggered. If logging the object with jQuery I can see that the attached change event is null. However, if running the following command manually in the Javascript console window it works:

```
$("select#phase1_type").trigger("change");
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong? I do not own the application, this is a Javascript executed via TamperMonkey.

Grateful for any input.

/Patrik

Comment: Unable to replicate, code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/18aebkjg/. If you have issues we'd need to see more of your code in order to replicate the issue

Comment: The only thing I can think of which could cause this behaviour is if you define the `change` event handler ***after*** you trigger the event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tampermonkey: Trigger event does not work for element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729519/tampermonkey-trigger-event-does-not-work-for-element)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sureI got you but you can use watch for the dorpdown list or anything similar to this

```
 $scope.$watch(function () { return self.filter; }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newFilter != oldFilter) {
                         // call trigger   
                        }
                    }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a duplicate question. That I've asked before. A bit awkward. :)

[Tampermonkey: Trigger event does not work for element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729519/tampermonkey-trigger-event-does-not-work-for-element)

Solved it with the following function:

```
function triggerEvent(e, s){
    "use strict";
    var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent(e, true, true);

    try {
        document.querySelector(s).dispatchEvent(event);
    } catch(err){
        console.log("Unable to fire event " + e + " on selector " + s);
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Looks like both web applications is using some transpiled framework which makes life hard for me by removing and re-adding elements to the DOM. Hope this helps someone else too.

/Patrik